# Looking for peek_byte on OCaml in_channel

Tags: io, ocaml

**Wanted**: a good way to input a single byte from an `in_channel` *without* consuming it.

---

[c](/questions/tagged/c)'s `ungetc` guarantees one character pushback.
But what do I do in OCaml?

Right now, I use `pos_in` + `input_byte` + `seek_in` for this. Crude! Also, this only works with repositionable channels.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, OCaml's standard library does not provide `ungetc`. The closest thing that comes to mind is the `Stream` module. Use `Stream.of_channel` to turn an `in_channel` into a stream and then you can use `Stream.peek` on it. But streams have a severely crippling interface (basically, just `Strream.peek` and `Stream.next`), so they are not that useful. Using the `ocamllex` lexer generator is a much better choice for anything a bit fancy.